# Why did Dr Staple make an announcement to the people in the restaurant?

Tags: glass, unbreakable-trilogy

In the superhero film *Glass* (2019), after she took down three men who thought they were super humans, Dr Staple showed up in the restaurant and made an announcement to the people in there:

[image: lady in a crowded restaurant]

> DR. STAPLE: All three were real. Quite special, actually. If you
>   approve, I will move to the next city.
>
> WOMAN: Will there be any repercussions?
>
> DR. STAPLE: No one saw them. I know what my charge is. Convince them.
>   This is the most humane and effective method.

Why did she make an announcement to the people in the restaurant?

Answer (score 2):

These are her bosses, colleagues, or some combination thereof. Although it may be unclear, Dr. Staple  works for an organization whose goal is to suppress the existence of superpowered individuals. As a psychologist, she tries to convince them that their powers are figments of their imaginations. If this fails, she tries to damage their brains so they aren't a threat (as with Glass) or contain them. Otherwise, she kills them, as a last resort. The people in this restaurant belong to the same group.

She's delivering a debriefing on her efforts with Overseer, the Beast, and Glass, which she believes to have been successful. The bit about the most humane method is essentially her justifying her actions: she's technically supposed to avoid violence, but all three supers ended up dead. Unfortunately for her, Glass outsmarted her, providing the world with evidence of indisputable superhuman abilities.

Comment: Another key point is that they (the members in the restaurant, Dr. Staple herself as well as the two assassins who kill the Beast and the Overseer) all have a small tattoo on their wrists of a 3-leaf clover (the norm versus a 4-leaf clover which would be 'rare'). Dr. Staple also reveals that this group has been preventing special people from emerging for 10,000 years.